# [Mendeley API]: How to search for partial terms

Tags: api, search, mendeley

I am using the Mendeley API to retrieve documents in the profile of a user.

Specifically, I am using this API:

```
GET https://api.mendeley.com/search/documents?view=all&limit=25&title=ONTOLOGY
```

I would like to search for all the documents that match a partial term, i.e. instead of the full word "ONTOLOGY" I would like to get the same result if I do an HTTP call like

```
GET https://api.mendeley.com/search/documents?view=all&limit=25&title=ONTOLO
```

How can I achieve that?

Should I put any jolly character?

I tried

```
ONTOLO*
ONTOLO$
ONTOLO?
```

with no luck.

I haven't found any documentation related to this feature.

Thanks!!